# Complete a select with data obtained after doing a data search, more or less

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

Very good to all, I'll try to raise this doubt that my head is almost hairless (or whatever it's said there in the USA when a problem makes your life impossible), and I have not been able to correctly raise google without encountering me With a setback..

In a form to update the data

```
<div class="form">
<form method="post" action="actualizar.php" target="_self" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="fichatecnica" value="<?php echo $busqueda; ?>">

    <table class="tabla" align="center">
    <caption>
      <h1 align="center">FICHA TECNICA</h1>
    </caption>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>
                <strong>Planta:</strong>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="5">
            <input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre; ?>" size="120" maxlength="100" placeholder="Nombre de planta">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>
                <strong>Ubicaci&oacute;n:</strong>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="5">
            <input type="text" name="ubicacion" value="<?php echo $ubicacion; ?>" size="120" maxlength="100" placeholder="Ubicaci&oacute;n">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>
                <strong>Recurso Humano:</strong>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="text" name="recurso_humano" value="<?php echo $recurso_humano; ?>" size="30" maxlength="20" placeholder="Cantidad">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>
                <strong>Tipo de Mezcla que Produce:</strong>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="text" name="tipo_mezcla" value="<?php echo $tipo_mezcla; ?>" size="40" maxlength="30" placeholder="Tipo de mezcla">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>
                <strong>Modelo y especificaciones de la planta de Asfalto:</strong>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="5">
            <input type="text" name="especific_planta" value="<?php echo $especific_planta; ?>" size="120" maxlength="100" placeholder="Especificaciones">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>
                <strong>Tipo de Planta:</strong>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="tipo_planta">
                <?php
                    $plantaf = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tipo_planta") or die ("No se pudeo ejecutar la consulta");
                    while ($datosPlanta = mysql_fetch_array($plantaf)){
                        echo '<option value="'.$datosPlanta["id_tipo_planta"].'">'.$datosPlanta["tipo_planta"].'</option>';
                    }
                    if ($tipo_planta = $datosPlanta["tipo_planta"]){
                        $pfisica = $datosPlanta["tipo_planta"];
                        echo '<option value="'.$pfisica.'">'.$pfisica.'</p>';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>
                <strong>Capacidad de Producci&oacute;n NOMINAL TON/H:</strong>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="produccion_nominal" value="<?php echo $produccion_nominal; ?>" size="20" maxlength="20" placeholder="NOMINAL">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>
                <strong>Capacidad de Producci&oacute;n EFECTIVA TON/H:</strong>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="produccion_efectiva" value="<?php echo $produccion_efectiva; ?>" size="20" maxlength="20" placeholder="EFECTIVA">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>
                <strong>Modelo y especificaciones del Tren de Trituraci&oacute;n:</strong>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="5">
            <input type="text" name="especific_tren" value="<?php echo $especific_tren; ?>" size="120" maxlength="100" placeholder="Especificaciones">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>
                <strong>Tipo de Tren de Trituraci&oacute;n:</strong>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="tipo_tren">
                <?php
                /* Cargar todas las variables, anexar la variable solicitada, comparar, y agregar*/
                    $trent = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tipo_tren") or die ("No se pudeo ejecutar la consulta");
                    while ($datosTren = mysql_fetch_array($trent)){
                        echo '<option value="'.$datosTren["id_tipo_tren"].'">'.$datosTren["tipo_tren"].'</option>';
                    }
                    echo '<p>'.$tipo_tren.'</p>';
                ?>
            </select>
            <?php


            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>
                <strong>Capacidad Nominal TON/H:</strong>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <input type="text" name="capacidad_tren" value="<?php echo $capacidad_tren; ?>" size="40" maxlength="30" placeholder="Capacidad">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">
            <h2 align="center">MATERIA PRIMA</h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>
                <strong>Agregado:</strong>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="5">
            <textarea name="caracteristica_materia_1" cols="100" rows="3"><?php echo $caracter_materia_1; ?></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>
                <strong>Arrocillo Polvillo y Piedra:</strong>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="5">
            <textarea name="caracteristica_materia_2" cols="100" rows="3"><?php echo $caracter_materia_2; ?></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>
                <strong>Arena:</strong>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="5">
            <textarea name="caracteristica_materia_3" cols="100" rows="3"><?php echo $caracter_materia_3; ?></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- <tr>
        <td colspan="6">
            <h2 align="center">REGISTRO FOTOGRAFICO</h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <label>
            <strong>Imagen 1:</strong>
          </label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <label>
            <strong>Imagen 2:</strong>
          </label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <label>
            <strong>Imagen 3:</strong>
          </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input type="file" name="imagen_1" id="imagen_1">
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input type="file" name="imagen_2" id="imagen_2">
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input type="file" name="imagen_3" id="imagen_3">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <output id="list_1">$imagen_1</output>
          <script>
              function archivo(evt) {
                  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

                  // Obtenemos la imagen del campo "file".
                  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
                    //Solo admitimos im&aacute;genes.
                    if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                        return function(e) {
                          // Insertamos la imagen
                         document.getElementById("list_1").innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" widht="250" height="250" src="', e.target.result,'" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                        };
                    })(f);

                    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
                  }
              }

              document.getElementById('imagen_1').addEventListener('change', archivo, false);
          </script>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <output id="list_2">$imagen_2</output>
          <script>
              function archivo(evt) {
                  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

                  // Obtenemos la imagen del campo "file".
                  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
                    //Solo admitimos im&aacute;genes.
                    if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                        return function(e) {
                          // Insertamos la imagen
                         document.getElementById("list_2").innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" widht="250" height="250" src="', e.target.result,'" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                        };
                    })(f);

                    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
                  }
              }

              document.getElementById('imagen_2').addEventListener('change', archivo, false);
          </script>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <output id="list_3">$imagen_3</output>
          <script>
              function archivo(evt) {
                  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

                  // Obtenemos la imagen del campo "file".
                  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
                    //Solo admitimos im&aacute;genes.
                    if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                        return function(e) {
                          // Insertamos la imagen
                         document.getElementById("list_3").innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" widht="250" height="250" src="', e.target.result,'" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                        };
                    })(f);

                    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
                  }
              }

              document.getElementById('imagen_3').addEventListener('change', archivo, false);
          </script>
        </td>
    </tr> -->
    <tr>
        <td>
          <label>
            <strong>Capacidad M&aacute;xima productiva d&iacute;a (TON):</strong>
          </label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="5">
          <input type="text" name="produccion_maxima" value="<?php echo $produccion_maxima; ?>" size="120" maxlength="100" placeholder="Producci&oacute;n m&aacute;xima">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
          <label>
            <strong>Precio de la Mezcla asf&aacute;ltica (TON) Bs.:</strong>
          </label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="5">
          <input type="text" name="precio" size="120" value="<?php echo $precio; ?>" maxlength="100" placeholder="Precio (usar . para decimales)">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" align="center"><input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar datos"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
```

(sorry if the text in my native language, I can not translate it properly), I can't bring the values ​​of a combo select to update it when required (lines 65 to 72 and 112 to 118).

The data (all of them), I get from this file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>BUSCAR</title>
    <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="index.php">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="mostrarDatos.php">Mostrar Datos</a></li>
                <li>Buscar</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="form">
        <?php

               include("conexion.php");

               // Agregar las variables a usar
               $registros = '';
               $texto = '';

               // Agregar las variables que se obtendrán de los campos
               $nombre = '';
               $ubicacion = '';
               $recurso_humano = '';
               $tipo_mezcla = '';
               $especific_planta = '';
               $produccion_nominal = '';
               $produccion_efectiva = '';
               $especific_tren = '';
               $capacidad_tren = '';
               $produccion_maxima = '';
               $precio = '';
               $tipo_planta = '';
               $tipo_tren = '';
               // ----------------------------------------------------------
               $caracter_materia_1 = '';
               $caracter_materia_2 = '';
               $caracter_materia_3 = '';
               //-----------------------------------------------------------
               $imagen_1 = '';
               $imagen_2 = '';
               $imagen_3 = '';

               // Comrpobar que el valor de búsqueda está disponible
               // Si está vacío mostrar el formulario de búsqueda
               if(!$_POST){
           ?>

        <!-- Insertar el formulario de HTML -->
        <form id="buscador" name="buscador" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">

            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><h1 align="center">BUSCAR</h1></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label> <strong>Buscar por ID:</strong> </label></td>
                    <td><input id="buscar" name="buscar" type="search" placeholder="Valor num&eacute;rico" autofocus ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="buscador" value="buscar"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <?php
               // En caso contrario mostrar los datos
           } else {

               $busqueda = $_POST["buscar"];

               // Comprobar si la búsqueda no tiene datos y mostrar un error
               if (empty($busqueda)){
                   $texto = '<h1 align="center">B&uacute;squeda sin resultados.&nbsp;<a href="javascript:window.history.back();">Volver</a></h1>';
                } // Comprobar si hay un valor que no es número y mostrar un error
                else if (strcmp($busqueda, strval(intval($busqueda)))){
                  $texto = '<h1 align="center">No es un valor num&eacute;rico. <a href="javascript:window.history.back();">Volver</a></h1>';
                } else { // Hay valor numérico, mostrar los datos hallados

                    // Consultar la base de datos, usando el comparador LIKE y asignamos el comodín lo pasado en la caja de búsqueda
                    $res_planta = mysql_query("SELECT id_planta, nombre, recurso_humano, ubicacion, tipo_mezcla, especific_planta, produccion_nominal, produccion_efectiva, especific_tren, capacidad_tren, produccion_maxima, precio, tipo_planta, tipo_tren FROM planta_fisica
    INNER JOIN tipo_planta, tipo_tren WHERE planta_fisica.fk_tipo_planta = tipo_planta.id_tipo_planta AND planta_fisica.fk_tipo_tren = tipo_tren.id_tipo_tren
    AND id_planta LIKE '%" .$busqueda. "%'") or die("No se pudo ejecutar la consulta");

                    $res_materia = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM materia_prima WHERE id_materia LIKE '%" .$busqueda. "%'") or die("No se pudo ejecutar la consulta");

                    $res_imagenes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM imagenes WHERE id_imagen LIKE '%" .$busqueda. "%'") or die("No se pudo ejecutar la consulta");

                    // Si los campos están vacíos, mostrar un mensaje
                    if (mysql_num_rows($res_planta) <= 0 || mysql_num_rows($res_materia) <= 0 || mysql_num_rows($res_imagenes) <=0){
                     $texto = '<h2 align="center">NO HAY RESULTADOS EN LA BASE DE DATOS</h2>';
                    } else { // En caso contrario, almacenar los datos obtenidos...
                        // ... primero, los de la planta física;
                        while($planta = mysql_fetch_array($res_planta)){
                            $id_planta = $planta["id_planta"];
                            $nombre = $planta["nombre"];
                            $recurso_humano = $planta["recurso_humano"];
                            $ubicacion = $planta["ubicacion"];
                            $tipo_mezcla = $planta["tipo_mezcla"];
                            $especific_planta = $planta["especific_planta"];
                            $produccion_nominal = $planta["produccion_nominal"];
                            $produccion_efectiva = $planta["produccion_efectiva"];
                            $especific_tren = $planta["especific_tren"];
                            $capacidad_tren = $planta["capacidad_tren"];
                            $produccion_maxima = $planta["produccion_maxima"];
                            $precio = $planta["precio"];
                            $tipo_planta = $planta["tipo_planta"];
                            $tipo_tren = $planta["tipo_tren"];
                        }

                        // ahora los de la materia prima;
                        while ($materia = mysql_fetch_array($res_materia)){
                            $id_materia = $materia["id_materia"];
                            $caracter_materia_1 = $materia["caracteristica_materia_1"];
                            $caracter_materia_2 = $materia["caracteristica_materia_2"];
                            $caracter_materia_3 = $materia["caracteristica_materia_3"];
                        }

                        // y por último, las imágenes
                        while($imagen = mysql_fetch_array($res_imagenes)){
                            $id_imagen = $imagen["id_imagen"];
                            $imagen_1 = $imagen["imagen_1"];
                            $imagen_2 = $imagen["imagen_2"];
                            $imagen_3 = $imagen["imagen_3"];
                        }
                    }

                    // mostrar los datos en una tabla
                    $texto = '
                    <table class="tabla" align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <caption>PLANTA FISICA</caption>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>id</td><td>Nombre</th><td>Recurso Humano</td><td>Ubicaci&oacute;n</td><td>Tipo de Mezcla</td><td>Especificaci&oacute;n Planta</td><td>Tipo de Planta</td><td>Producci&oacute;n NOMINAL</td><td>Producci&oacute;n EFECTIVA</td><td>Tipo de Tren</td><td>Especificaci&oacute;n Tren</td><td>Capacidad M&aacute;xima</td><td>Producci&oacute;n M&aacute;xima</td><td>Precio</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>'.$id_planta.'</th>
                            <td>'.$nombre.'</td>
                            <td>'.$recurso_humano.'</td>
                            <td>'.$ubicacion.'</td>
                            <td>'.$tipo_mezcla.'</td>
                            <td>'.$especific_planta.'</td>
                            <td>'.$tipo_planta.'</td>
                            <td>'.$produccion_nominal.'</td>
                            <td>'.$produccion_efectiva.'</td>
                            <td>'.$tipo_tren.'</td>
                            <td>'.$especific_tren.'</td>
                            <td>'.$capacidad_tren.'</td>
                            <td>'.$produccion_maxima.'</td>
                            <td>'.$precio.'</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    <table class="tabla" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2" align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <caption>MATERIA PRIMA</caption>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>id</th><td>Agregado</td><td>Arrocillo Polvillo y Piedra</td><td>Arena</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>'.$id_materia.'</th>
                            <td>'.$caracter_materia_1.'</td>
                            <td>'.$caracter_materia_2.'</td>
                            <td>'.$caracter_materia_3.'</td></tr>
                    </table>

                    <table class="tabla" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2" align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <caption>IMAGENES</caption>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>id</th><td>Primera imagen</td><td>Segunda imagen</td><td>Tercera imagen</td>
                        </tr>
                        <output id="list">
                        <tr>
                            <th>'.$id_imagen.'</th>
                            <td>'.$imagen_1.'</td>
                            <td>'.$imagen_2.'</td>
                            <td>'.$imagen_3.'</td>
                        </tr>
                        </output>
                    </table>';

                    include ('form.php');
                }
            }

            echo $texto;
            ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

previously creating some variables. I created previously a table to check the data, and yes, it shows them; but I have no idea how to display the values ​​of the above-mentioned lines. I have tried various formulas to display the data, and don't even appear. And the select is still empty. I would like to be pushed in the right direction to get these values, because I have not had my head calm for almost a week.

Comment: Sorry if I presented it with links. Since in a previous doubt that I realized I was being asked to share the code, I did it as I was suggested to me that is correct: for really long codes always suggest sharing a link to sites like pastebin so it can be better read.

Comment: if this is "a problem that makes your life impossible", what would you call a situation in which you have no oxygen to breathe?

Answer (score 0):

I must say first of all thank you very much for giving me the required patience. Due to the busy schedule and the many questions of the users of this platform, perhaps it would not respond with the urgency that needed. But after discussing with other users in an area forum, I managed to find the answer:

The solution is attached in this code, the same one I included before, but with a pretty obvious difference (I knew it had to be a single line):

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="tipo_planta">
            <?php
                $plantaf = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tipo_planta") or die ("No se pudeo ejecutar la consulta");
                while ($datosPlanta = mysql_fetch_array($plantaf)){
                    **echo '<option value="'.$datosPlanta["id_tipo_planta"].'"';
                    if ($tipo_planta == $datosPlanta["tipo_planta"]) echo "selected";
                    echo '>'.$datosPlanta["tipo_planta"].'</option>';**
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="tipo_tren">
            <?php
            /* Cargar todas las variables, anexar la variable solicitada, comparar, y agregar*/
                $trent = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tipo_tren") or die ("No se pudeo ejecutar la consulta");
                while ($datosTren = mysql_fetch_array($trent)){
                    **echo '<option value="'.$datosTren["id_tipo_tren"].'"';
                    if ($tipo_tren == $datosTren["tipo_tren"]) echo "selected";
                    echo '>'.$datosTren["tipo_tren"].'</option>';**
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And after saving, and loading the search request, finally the select are located just above the value obtained, and the checks and validations work correctly. Then, change the values and redo the search, and finally displays the changed values.